How can I browse my models which are uploaded on S3 APS bucket using simple viewer?
I have followed the tutorial to upload my revit model on Autodesk platform services S3 bucket and then view them by simple viewer provided my them. Now I want to see these models like where they are stored i am unable to acces them.

Did you follow this tutorial ? Simple Viewer  In this tutorial, you will get a dropdown on top right with a list of all your models that you can load on the viewer.

There are multiple ways of checking, you can check in https://oss-manager.autodesk.io or using Postman collections or from the simple viewer sample at the right top corner drop down list.
